# Why is realloc() mysteriously behaving differently when compiled for C++?

Tags: c++, c, realloc

I have the following function that I've used in C programs plenty of times before:

```
/**
    Splits a given string into an array of strings using given delimiters.
    @param input_string
        The string to be split.
    @param delimiters
        The characters that will be used as delimiters.
    @return
        The components of the split string followed by @c NULL , or only
        @c NULL if sufficient memory fails to allocate for the returned array.
 */
char **split(char *input_string, const char *delimiters) {
    char **components = NULL;
    int components_count = 0;

    char *component = strtok(input_string, delimiters);
    while (component) {
        ++components_count;

        // |components| is reallocated to accomodate |component|. If
        // |realloc()| fails, |NULL| is returned.
        components = realloc(components, sizeof(char *) * components_count);
        if (!components) return NULL;
        components[components_count - 1] = component;

        component = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    // |components| is reallocated once more to accomodate an additional
    // |NULL|. Only |NULL| is returned in |realloc()| fails.
    components = realloc(components, sizeof(char *) * (components_count + 1));
    if (!components) {
        return NULL;
    }
    components[components_count] = NULL;

    return components;
}
```

I just recently added the function to a C++ project to use in a situation where I was required to deal with C-strings. When compiling, I now get this errors:

```
error: assigning to 'char **' from incompatible type 'void *'
        components = realloc(components, sizeof(char *) * components_count);

error: assigning to 'char **' from incompatible type 'void *'
    components = realloc(components, sizeof(char *) * (components_count + 1));
```

I'm completely lost as to what to do about these errors. As far as I'm concerned, what I'm doing should be legal in C++ since it's always worked fine in C. Any insight?

If it helps, I'm am using clang++ on OS X as a compiler, but this code is also expected to compile with g++ on Ubuntu.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74597/discussion-on-question-by-jared-why-is-realloc-mysteriously-behaving-different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything has to be the same on C and C++; `malloc` and `realloc` is a usual example of this.

1. You don't have to explicitly cast the `void pointer` in C, it will be done automatically, as in your example.
2. You definitely have to explicitly cast that pointer in C++, both in `malloc` and `realloc` functions.

There is a great deal of differences between those two languages, don't take everything for granted.

In this link some differences on basic stuff between C and C++ are stated here; it might be worth reading it.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html

Or this (suggested by a comment):

http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm

Comment: Glad this had such a simple solution. Added `(char **)` before each `realloc()` call, and everything works well. Thanks for the useful link.

Comment: That website isn't accurate at all! The last point it makes is flat-out wrong. All three C standards contain something along the lines of this quote: ["reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0."](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3) indeed it is true that C and C++ are completely different languages, though they commonly have compatible ABIs (as does assembly, D, etc). If you're looking for a valid link to support that statement, [this one goes into much more detail, however outdated it is](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm).

Comment: It might also be worth reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1989425)...

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't allow `void*` pointers to be implicitly converted to other pointers. Also, C and C++ are quite different languages, so not all of C will work on C++ because it is a different language.

Explicitly casting the `realloc()` result should work however.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate your C code from your C++ code. They are different languages. Treating C as though it can run in C++ makes about as much sense as treating Traditional Chinese as though it can run in Simplified Chinese. If you're writing a program to compile with a C++ compiler, it should probably look very different to the program you write to compile with a C compiler.

Nonetheless, there are times when you might want to link some C code (or assembly code, or whatever) to your C++ code. The process is probably similar for every language, providing the compilers you're using have a compatible ABI. The example I'll use is `gcc` and `g++`.

Compile your C code using your C compiler (eg. `gcc`), but without the linking process (eg. using the `-c` flag). For example: `gcc -c split.c`

Compile your C++ code using your C++ compiler, and link the object code generated by your C compiler into it. For example: `g++ main.cpp split.o`